# NameError in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class

For this piece of code:

```
class myBaseClass
  def funcTest()
    puts "baseClass"
  end
end
myBaseClass.new.funcTest
```

I am getting an error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `myBaseClass' for main:Object
from c:/Users/Yurt/Documents/ruby/polymorphismTest.rb:9
from (irb):145:in `eval'
from (irb):145
from c:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):152:0> x=myBaseClass.new
```

When I try`x=myBaseClass.new`, I get:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `myBaseClass' for main:Object from (irb):152
```

Has someone already encountered this problem? I don't think my code can be wrong.

Comment: Emacs is irrelevant. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In ruby, all constants including class names must begin with a capital letter. `myBaseClass` would be interpreted as an undefined local variable. `MyBaseClass` would work properly.

Comment: Interestingly, you're allowed to do this: `class Foo; end; f = Foo; f.new`

Comment: That's because a class is an object and can be assigned to a variable. You can define and use a class without ever assigning it to a constant: `f=Class.new; f.new` gives you an instance of the unnamed class residing in the local variable `f`

Answer (score 6):

Your class name should start with a capital, working code below

```
class MyBaseClass
  def funcTest()
   puts "baseClass"
 end
end



MyBaseClass.new.funcTest
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong. Classnames must start with an uppercase in Ruby.

```
class MyBaseClass
```

fixes it.

What I don't get is how you don't get a clear error message like I do.

Comment: I am running ruby 1.9.2, on windows, gotten from the oneclick installer. Out of curiosity, what is the error message I should be getting?

Comment: my 1.9.2  p180 ( ubuntu) says: SyntaxError: (irb):1: class/module name must be CONSTANT

Answer (score 0):

### *Code working*

```
class MyBaseClass
  def funcTest()
   puts "baseClass"
 end
end
MyBaseClass.new.funcTest
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).