# Understanding ruby modules

Tags: ruby, eclipse, ruby-2.0, dltk

I am new to Ruby, using eclipse, DLTK ruby plugin and Ruby 2.0. I created an Ruby module file called AModule.rb which has the code:

```
module AModule
  aConstant = 7
end
```

This is called from a test ruby script in the same project:

```
require 'AModule'
puts AModule::aConstant
```

In the second line of the above code, i get the error `in '<main>': undefined local variable or method 'aModule' for main:Object (NameError)`

I followed my codeacademy tutorial, so I did not expect this to happen. What is the mistake that I am making here ?

PS: Actually, I wanted to name my module file **aM**odule.rb and not **AM**odule.rb . But, the DLTK plugin quietly makes the first alphabet uppercase. Could this be a bug ?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @sawa - Actually, I have defined it. I made a small lowercase mistake in puts. I fixed it now. The same error remains. Can you please upvote me to zero points if you see no error or shortcoming in my question ? Thanks.

Comment: My comment applies to your question after the edit (my deleted answer applied to your question before the edit). I will not follow your request to vote in any way. You are not supposed to ask for that. Furthermore, as I wrote, it cannot be reproduced.

Comment: @sawa - reproduced and fixed. I am using ruby 2.0.

Comment: @sawa - ruby is quite good, coming from java. But why is it so crappy ? Java never complained if i began a package name with a capital letter. But, ruby just throws up when module name and constants don't begin with capital letter.

Comment: Because Ruby has a syntax, just as Java. You can learn the syntax or change the language, I guess no one forces you to use Ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that name of constant must start with UpperCaseLetter. Otherwise Ruby will think of it as of local variable. So what's wrong with it? Short answer: it's all about scope. Local variables are only visible in their lexical scope.
Constant is a quite different thing. Constant can always be accessed via so called [namespace-resolution operator (`::`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about).

Read more info about Ruby scoping [here](https://aprescott.com/posts/variables-closures-and-scope).

Answer (score 0):

I used windows cmd instead of eclipse IDE. I'll show the steps I used to find the errors for the code and finally fix them. DLTK plugin is not at fault here. Module file and test script are in the same folder.

**LESSON -** Module name and constant name in modules MUST begin with capital letter. Why, I don't know.

**aModule.rb**

```
module aModule
aConstant = 7
end
```

**Test.rb**

```
require 'aModule'
puts aModule::aConstant
```

**cmd:** cd into Test.rb folder and `ruby Test.rb`
**error:** ``require': cannot load such file -- tokenizer.rb (LoadError)`
**help:** [Ruby 'require' error: cannot load such file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9750610/ruby-require-error-cannot-load-such-file)

> Ruby 1.9 has removed the current directory from the load path, and so
>   you will need to do a relative require on this file, as Pascal says:
>
> ```
> require './tokenizer'
> ```
>
> There's no need to suffix it with .rb, as Ruby's smart enough to know
>   that's what you mean anyway.

I made the following changes:

**Test.rb**

```
require './aModule'
puts aModule::aConstant
```

**cmd:** `ruby Test.rb`
**error:** `class/module name must be CONSTANT (SyntaxError)` in aModule.rb
**help:** [NameError in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486443/nameerror-in-ruby)

I made the following changes:

**aModule.rb**

```
module AModule # capital
aConstant = 7
end
```

**Test.rb**

```
require './AModule'
puts AModule::aConstant
```

**cmd:** ruby Test.rb
**error:** `undefined method 'aConstant' for AModule:Module (NoMethodError)`
**help:** Used the above link. I think constant must also be named with capital.

**Final working code:**

**aModule.rb**

```
module AModule # capital
AConstant = 7 # capital
end
```

**Test.rb**

```
require './AModule'
puts AModule::AConstant
```

WTF is Ruby like this ??? And why the hell do I need to append `./` before a module name when it is in the same folder as the test script ?

Comment: `./` explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900370/why-does-ruby-1-9-2-remove-from-load-path-and-whats-the-alternative)